# How to make hyperlink for selected text via modal

Tags: jquery

I can make hyperlink for selected text via JS prompt. But JS prompt only have a one input for url and I need more options like target and etc.. So I need to use modal for make hyperlink for selected text. How can I do this?
Jquery select event is enough for make this?

I did try: (but not working)

```
$(".text").select(function() {
alert("text selected 1");
});
```

I did try: (but not working)

```
$(".wrapper").on("select", ".text", function() {
alert("text selected 2");
});
```

HTML example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="list">
<div class="item"><div class="text" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum</div></div>
<div class="item"><div class="text" contenteditable="true">Test link</div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
//not working
$(".text").select(function() {
 alert("text selected 1");
});
//not working
$(".wrapper").on("select", ".text", function() {
alert("text selected 2");
});
//other code
});
```

How can I know selected text value via jquery?

Modal contains two inputs. First input for url and second one for target. Like this:

```
<input type="text" name="url" value="http://">
<select name="target">
<option value="_self">Default</option>
<option value="_blank">New Window</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

After submit from modal how can I bypass variables to selected text area for make hyperlink?

My jsfiddle example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/3Le1af4x/

Answer (score 0):

Just a way to get you started I setup this simple code.

You can check [Bootstrap's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) for native solutions.

```js
$(function() {



  $('#modal-submit').on('click', function(event) {
    var a = "";
    var loc = "";
    var url = $("#modal-url").val();
    var win = $("#modal-select").find(":selected").text();;
    if (win == "Default") {
      loc = "_self"
    } else if (win == "New Window") {
      loc = "_blank"
    }

    a = "<a href=''" + url + "' target='" + loc + "'>" + url + "</a>";
    $('body').append(a);

  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" id="link" class="btn btn-info" data-obj='{"name":"CreateLink", "prompt":true, "promptText":"Link:", "promptDefault":"http://"}'>JS LINK</a>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">MODAL LINK</button>
  </div>
  <p></p>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="text" contenteditable="true">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">image</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" name="url" id="modal-url" value="http://">
          <select id="modal-select" name="target">
            <option value="_self">Default</option>
            <option value="_blank">New Window</option>
          </select>
          <input id="modal-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It basically get the values from the `modal` and insert into variables then `append` the link to `body`.